# I'm not able to move to next page using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to do web scraping on reclameaqui site ([www.reclameaqui.com.br](http://www.reclameaqui.com.br)). The code is already done, but I'm not able to iretate over lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=1, lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=2, lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=3 and get its contents:

```
'''
This spider file contains the spider logic and scraping code. 
In order to determine what needs to go in this file, we have to inspect the website!
'''

import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

from complaintscraper.items.ComplaintItem import ComplaintItem
from complaintscraper.utils.DataCleaning import DataCleaning

import json
import pydash

class ComplaintScraper(CrawlSpider):

  name = "ComplaintScraper"  
  custom_settings = {
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 10,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 10,
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1
  }
  
  start_urls = [
    "https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/empresa/santander/lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=1",
    "https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/empresa/santander/lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=2",
    "https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/empresa/santander/lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=3"
  ]

  def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
      yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_complaint, dont_filter=True)
  
      
  def parse_complaint(self, response):
    for row in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"bJdtis")]'):
      link = row.xpath("./a/@href").get()
      yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_model_complaint, dont_filter=True)

  def get_data(self, data, query):
    return pydash.get(data, query, None)


  def parse_model_complaint(self, response):

    complaintItem = ComplaintItem()

    data = json.loads(response.xpath('//*[@id="__NEXT_DATA__"]//text()').extract()[0])
    
    complaintItem['id']               = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.legacyId")
    complaintItem['title']            = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.title")
    complaintItem['solved']           = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.solved")
    complaintItem['description']      = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.description")
    complaintItem['url']              = response.url

    content_container                 = response.xpath('//*[contains(@data-testid, "complaint-content-container")]//text()').extract()
    complaintItem['tags']             = content_container[content_container.index("ID:") + 2 : content_container.index("Status da reclamação:")]
    complaintItem['status']           = response.xpath('//*[contains(@data-testid, "complaint-status")]//text()').extract()
    
    complaintItem['userCity']         = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.userCity")
    complaintItem['userState']        = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.userState")
    complaintItem['creation_date']    = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.created")
    
    #Interactions contain customer and company replicas.
    complaintItem['deal_again']       = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.dealAgain")
    complaintItem['score']            = self.get_data(data, "props.pageProps.complaint.score")
      
    yield complaintItem
```

What I getting is three times the lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=1's contents (the're reppetead/similar). It was supposed to get all contents from lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=1, lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=2, lista-reclamacoes/?pagina=3).

[image]

Wher am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the next example

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ComplaintItem
import json


class ComplaintScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "complaintScraper"  

    start_urls = [f"https://iosearch.reclameaqui.com.br/raichu-io-site-search-v1/query/companyComplains/10/{item}?company=98" for item in range(0,100,10)]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
  
    def parse(self, response):

        complaintItem = ComplaintItem()

        data = json.loads(response.text)
      
        for card in data['complainResult']['complains']['data']:
            complaintItem = ComplaintItem()
            complaintItem['id']               = card['id']
            complaintItem['title']            = card['title']   
            complaintItem['description']      = card['description']
            complaintItem['url']              = response.url
            yield complaintItem
```

Comment: thanks for answering me, but your code still gets similar content for different pages.

Comment: Nice! But how can I get all 'interactions' per page? The interactions are the consumer and company replies/replica.  Any ideia?

Comment: All the required data are loaded via API. Your question was to implement the next pages correctly and it'sworking perfectly.  Rest of the  your task whatever  data  you would like to extract . You can raise  a new questoion for the next step.The solution of this question is end to here. That may a bit time consuming